# Point-free destructuring with GHC

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, union, ghc

I do not like to destructure sum typed values with pattern matching. It feels alien for me because of its pointed style.
I rather write and use `switch` functions for sum types.

My question is about any sum type generally, but i demonstrate it on `Either` as example :

```
data Processor cl cr r = MakeProcessor { l :: cl -> r, r :: cr -> r }

switch :: Processor cl cr r -> Either cl cr -> r
switch p ei = 
    case ei of
        Left x -> l p x
        Right x -> r p x
```

With this extension to `Either` :

instead of this :

```
map f e = 
    case e of
        Left x -> Left x
        Right x -> Right (f x)
```

i can write this :

```
map f = switch (MakeProcessor { l : Left, r : f >>> Right })
```

, which i feel nicer for most situations.

To write such extension stuff [`Processor`, `switch`] for a sum type is mechanical work. So i wonder : is there a way to make the compiler [GHC] do it for me? Or any other way to destructure sum typed values in pointless style?

---

Note : I used `Either` as just an example. `Either` was a wrong choice, as many readers thought that my question was about `Either` specifically, and hence pointed me to `either`. I should have used a sum type that is not in the base library, like

```
data Result a b = Fail a | Success b
```

Comment: You might find the "lens" library helpful.  It would allow you to write your `map` function as `over _Right`.

Comment: I guess that _Right comes from TemplateHaskell, right? Maybe this is too strict, but i was avoiding TH because it is not compatible with SafeHaskell.

Comment: My `Either` example is just an example of my method to avoid pattern matching. It is a safer version of the `either`  function in the base library. My question is not about specifically `Either`, i use it only as example.

Comment: `_Right` is not TemplateHaskell.  It's a function defined in Lens.  (Lens can make use of TH to automate lens generation for user-defined types, but it doesn't require TH.)

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you want to achieve here - the fact that you "feel" the latter is "nicer" is entirely subjective. The type `Processor a b r` is isomorphic to `Either a b -> r`, so you haven't changed anything, semantically speaking, as your `switch` function is just function application composed with one direction of said isomorphism.

Comment: ""nicer" is entirely subjective" - it is nicer in the same sense that pointless style is nicer.

Comment: I do not want to "change something semantically".

Comment: You just need `either` since you can map any sum type to a nested `Either`

Comment: @user2407038, many stylistic things are subjective.  I think this is a fairly subjective question, yet still valid.  Also, there is another aspect: "niceness" has not only an individual definition, but a community definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no (especially without Template Haskell).

However, like many constructs in functional programming, you can turn it upside down.  Use a Church/Scott encoding (they are the same when the datatype is not recursive).

```
newtype ChurchEither a b = ChurchEither { switch :: forall c. (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> c }
```

in which you get the eliminator `switch` for free, because it's the definition of the type, but you have to write the constructors yourself

```
left x = ChurchEither (\l r -> l x)
right x = ChurchEither (\l r -> r x)
```

so you haven't really gained anything boilerplate-wise.

Comment: I consider your first line as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

The `either` function lets you specify separate functions to apply to `Left` and `Right` values in an `Either a b` value:

```
switch p ei = either (l p) (r p) ei
```

You can immediately drop `ei` from both sides to get

```
switch p = either (l p) (r p)
```

and you can use the `Applicative` instance for functions to drop `p`:

```
switch = either <$> l <*> r
```

For an arbitrary sum type, you need to provide an appropriate *catamorphism*, which is the fancy name for a function like `either` that reduces a value wrapped by the sum type to the wrapped type.

Comment: My `Either` example is just an example of my method to avoid pattern matching. It is a safer version of the `either`  function in the base library. My question is not about specifically `Either`, i use it only as example.

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which your method is safer than `either`?

Comment: More safe : 
A possible coding mistake is to flip the order of the parameters of `either`. If the type of values stored in `Either` are equal than there will be no typing error.
`Either` is a bad example to demonstrate this kind of mistake possibility, but i think generally for other sum types the danger is real. Hence i rather put the processor functions into a record, just so that i can name them.

Comment: `switch p = either (l p) (r p)` - you just hid the pattern matching inside `either`. Someone had to write `either`, using pattern matching. I hoped the compiler can be that someone.